# how to list the images stored by google compute engine using PHP?

Tags: php, google-compute-engine

I am using PHP sdk in order to list all the images available in Google compute engine account. 
Here is my code:

```
$images= $this->service->listImages($projectID, $optionalArray);    
$image = $images->getItems();
```

It is returning empty array even though I have images in my account

Comment: Would you share your code in Pastebin.com so I can try to reproduce on my account?

Comment: Here it is http://pastebin.com/7jcrhqH0

Comment: Thank you,just a confirmation: are you using https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client ?

Comment: Yes I am using the same github link

Comment: @PaoloP. Any idea why it is not displaying images?

Comment: could you please paste all code with class includes and authentication (omitting keys and secret) ? Thanks

Comment: listimage() method works, but how to fetch public images in GCE?

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the listImages() function will list only the private images created by you with command "gcloud compute images create ...".

For your reference private images are documented at [1].

Link:
[1] - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#private_images

Regards,
Paolo